# Postgres split string with double quotes to multiple rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|        ID (int)     |     Location (string)                         |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|         1           |    ["Humboldt, TN","Medina, TN","Milan, TN"]  |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
```

I want to turn it into a table that looks like this:

```
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|        ID (int)     |     Location (string)                         |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|         1           |    Humboldt, TN                               |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|         1           |    Medina, TN                                 |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|         1           |    Milan, TN                                  |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
```

What would the query look like? I'm thinking I could split the text on a `,` but I'd need a way to ignore commas within double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` string is similar to a text array. Convert it to `text[]` and unnest:

```
with my_data(id, location) as (
values 
    (1, '["Humboldt, TN","Medina, TN","Milan, TN"]')
)

select id, unnest(format('{%s}', trim(location, '[]'))::text[]) as location
from my_data

 id |   location   
----+--------------
  1 | Humboldt, TN
  1 | Medina, TN
  1 | Milan, TN
(3 rows)
```

Or even simpler, cast the string to `jsonb` and use `jsonb_array_elements_text()`:

```
with my_data(id, location) as (
values 
    (1, '["Humboldt, TN","Medina, TN","Milan, TN"]')
)

select id, jsonb_array_elements_text(location::jsonb) as location
from my_data
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=564cbe2fa6fd82a5f8a0171fb0b4834a)

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question.